# How can I filter this pandas dataframe based with substrings and row counts stored in another dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, list-comprehension, data-filtering

I have a dataframe that contains groups of people's names in a column as a string.
Then I also have a dataframe that contains a list of people's names (1 dataframe row per person's name). Sample dataset as described:

```
    groupsofpeople = pd.DataFrame({'group':['Genie, Chris, Mike, Dee','Chase, Chris, 
        William S.','Mike, Tim', 'William S., Chris, Tim'], 'rank':[1,2,3,4]})
    people = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Chris','Chase','Ross Rick', 'William S.'], 
        'rowcnt':[30,25,15,25]})

                          group  rank
    0   Genie, Chris, Mike, Dee     1
    1  Chase, Chris, William S.     2
    2                 Mike, Tim     3
    3    William S., Chris, Tim     4

    >>> people
             name  rowcnt
    0       Chris      2
    1       Chase      3
    2   Ross Rick      1
    3  William S.      2
```

My goal is to iterate through the 'people' dataframe names and locate rows in groupsofpeople if 1 of the names in the group match. The extra caveat to this is that I also want to filter each row to only return the number of people in the rowcnt column. So if groupsofpeople dataframe has 5 rows with Chris in it, this statement before the filter is applied, then after the substring is found, only the first 2 rows are returned (as the groupsofpeople area in a specific order).

I dont have a full grasp on list comprehension to pull this off on my own, but I can tell you that this hardcoded solution would give the result of what I am striving towards if there is a way to loop through the names (in the str.contains()) as well as the rowcnt (in the head()):

```
    founddf = groupsofpeople[groupsofpeople['group'].str.contains('Chris')].head(2)
    upload = pd.concat([upload,founddf],ignore_index=False, sort=False)
    founddf = groupsofpeople[groupsofpeople['group'].str.contains('Chase')].head(3)
    upload = pd.concat([upload,founddf],ignore_index=False, sort=False)
    founddf = groupsofpeople[groupsofpeople['group'].str.contains('Ross Rick')].head(1)
    upload = pd.concat([upload,founddf],ignore_index=False, sort=False)
```

This is the result I would like to get to without hardcoding the loop/iterations):

```
          group                  rank
       Chase, Chris, William S.     2
       Genie, Chris, Mike, Dee      1
       Chase, Chris, William S.     2
```

Can anyone help me achieve this solution?

Comment: are you sure your example output is correct? If yes, can you explain how [my proposed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68797216/16343464) is incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to output the first n rows per person according to the 'rowcnt' value in the `people` dataframe

```
names = set(people.name)
people2 = people.set_index('name')

(groupsofpeople
 .assign(group_list=groupsofpeople['group'].str.split(', ').apply(lambda x: set(x).intersection(names)))
 .explode('group_list')
 .dropna(subset=['group_list'])
 .groupby(['group_list'])
 .apply(lambda d: d.head(people2.loc[d.name, 'rowcnt']))
 .reset_index(drop=True)
 #.drop('group_list', axis=1) #kept here to see groups
)
```

output:

```
                      group  rank  group_list
0  Chase, Chris, William S.     2       Chase
1   Genie, Chris, Mike, Dee     1       Chris
2  Chase, Chris, William S.     2       Chris
3  Chase, Chris, William S.     2  William S.
4    William S., Chris, Tim     4  William S.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I just copied this and ran it now. Your output looks exactly what Im looking for, except when I run your code I get a type error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'     which I believe is coming from the lambda function. Not quite sure why yet though?

Comment: I had to convert that set to a list and it appears to have worked! 
new line is  .assign(group_list=groupsofpeople['group'].str.split(', ').apply(lambda x: list(set(x).intersection(names))))
Hopefully that isnt expected to cause an issue?
Thanks again for your help as I have been working on this all day.

Comment: Done! As a read through the logic and try and get better, I will admit, I am slightly confused still as to the logic you used to put this all together? I wanna say I have used all of these functions individually before  but yet -> would not be able to put this together on my own. Do you mind writing a brief summary of logic? That may help me process this better if you can just walk me through.